# "Прошлым летом"

Tags: лексика

Сегодня за столом возник такой спор.  Когда мы говорим "прошлым летом", то имеем в виду последнее прошедшее лето или лето прошлого года? Например, один из оппонентов утверждал, что сегодня, в апреле 2012 "прошлое лето" для него - это лето 2011 года, а вот в сентябре 2011 г. "прошлым петом" он считал бы лето 2010 года. А вот другой спорящий утверждал, что логичнее уже 1-го сентября только что ушедшее лето считать "прошлым". Третий из споривших поинтересовался: "31-го декабря 2011 года считается, что  "прошлое лето" - это лето 2010 г., а уже  1-го января 2012 "прошлым" считается лето 2011?" Так где же она - граница? В то же время если в сентябре или декабре сказать "нынешнее лето", то всем понятно, что речь идёт о лете текущего года. А вот в апреле "нынешним летом" уже не скажешь. Может, я несколько путано выразила свою мысль, но мне интересно, что по этому поводу думают другие участники нашего  портала. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Эти вещи никакими писаными нормами не регулируются. Смотреть надо по контексту.
Но по моим представлениям прошлое лето - последнее прошедшее. Все разговоры про 31 декабря - от лукавого.

Answer (score 1):

Для меня прошлое лето - это лето прошлого года, а нынешнее лето - лето нынешнего года.

Answer (score 0):

Спор ни о чём, потому что первые два "оппонента" рассматривают понятие *прошлое лето* в разных плоскостях: один говорит о последовательности (прошлое лето, это/нынешнее лето, следующее лето), а другой — о временном "статусе" (лето прошло, лето идёт, лето будет).

Comment: Оно, может, и так, что в разных плоскостях, но вопрос не праздный. Значение выражения должно быть понято и истолковано. Иначе возникает коммуникативный барьер.

Comment: Вопрос не праздный, согласен, но что может форум? Тут, по-моему, та же сложность, что и "вверх/вниз по улице". Как люди определяют — непонятно, мы лишь можем попытаться построить какое-то общее правило.

Comment: А спор-то не об этом. Не о том, кто прав из "двух первых оппонентов", а о том, какая семантика у слова "прошлый". И достаточно ли понятно выражение "прошлым летом" массе.  И как быть, если оно непонятно. Ну примерно. Спорить же от том, кто прав в своем понимании, бесполезно, это очевидно.

Comment: Насколько я могу судить, люди под "прошлым летом" понимают лето прошлого года. Возможно, что само выражение "прошлое лето" построено по аналогии с "прошлым годом" и понимается в этом контексте.

Answer (score 0):

Тут еще есть умники, которые считают *прошлым летом* лето 2021 года (речь про сегодняшний день, март 2023 года), а лето 22 года считают настоящим, лето 23 — будущим. Вот такая петрушка.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два вида времени - цикличное и временной промежуток.

Прошлое лето - лето прошлого года. Связано с годичным циклом, лето - это год: *сколько тебе лет, сколько тебе годков*.

А в сентябре - лето прошедшее.

В классике *прошлое лето* практически не встречается, грубо говоря, есть два периода - год, дающий жизнь, когда можно нажить что-то, вырастить, заработать, прожить и зима, которую нужно пережить. Очевидно, у предков не было часов и календарей в карманных гаджетах.

Год берёт начало не первого января, а где-то, когда Масленица, когда сжигают чучело Зимы. Когда природа просыпается и начинается новый виток от смерти к жизни - от зимы к лету, значит, возникает будущее лето, а прошедшее лето становится прошлым, прошлогодним.

Однако у современных людей живущих в линейном времени год начинается и кончается 1 января, потому что Дед Мороз, президент, смартфон так сказал. Ну и проблем зиму пережить нет. Поэтому у некоторых появляется еще и *позапрошлогоднее лето*, по аналогу позавчера, вот *послебудущих лет* уже как-то не получается - не срослось.